# Email doesn't get sent if it includes a specific URL

Tags: emails

Using AcyMailing to send out a Newsletter to our group. The Newsletter has a number of links to our sponsors' websites.
IF I include a link to one very specific URL, the email never gets sent. AcyMailing reports it as sent, but no-one receives it. If I remove that URL, the exact same email gets sent no problem. I can use a bit.ly substitute and that works. Thought maybe it was the .org somehow being filtered out as invalid and tried other .org addresses, and they all worked. Even went and put in other URLs hosted on the same server (thinking that maybe the server IP was blacklisted) and they got through fine.

AcyMailing support suggested trying the other mail options, but none of them worked. So not sure that it is AcyMailing's fault. Also tried talking to both our hosting (Gatorhost) and the hosting for the errant URL (A Small Orange) but they weren't able to help me either.
Has anyone ever encountered this? Or have suggestions as to why an email would be blocked just because of a specific link?
Thanks.

Comment: try posting this on acymailing forum.

Comment: Are you using PHP or SMTP? If SMTP, is that the same server on "Gatorhost" that hosts the site?

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but some suggestions:

1. Is there something unusual about that specific URL that would be causing acymailing (or some other component) to have a problem sending it?
   Maybe contains spaces or other character?
   References a type of document that is getting the email blocked without warning?
2. Have you tried sending that url in an email outside acymailing/Joomla to determine if the problem is within acymailing or just a general problem with that URL?

Answer (score 1):

Use Acymailing spam test option.

The test will give you some clues about the rejected URL.

I suggest also to use this service:

https://www.mail-tester.com/

and againg check the report.